# Convergence of Series; given limit inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm studying for an exam over series, and here is a question that I cannot complete.

Let $a_1,a_2,...>0$. Prove that if

$\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)>1$ then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

I've tried rewriting the given inequality in terms of the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, but then the inequality becomes

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$, so that the ratio test would be inconclusive. I'm not seeing the algebra required to ensure the series converges.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You really have two cases, one where $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ approaches a limit bigger than one, or if the limit is exactly one. The other cases contradict the premise. In the first case, you are automatically done. In the second, you have that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \approx 1 + \frac{C}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ asymptotically, where $C > 1$. Some sort of comparison would be in order there.

Comment: This is, in fact, Raabe's test - you can read more e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$b_n=\frac{1}{n^p},\ q=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right).$$

And we know $p =\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right).$

When q > 1, there exists p, such that q > p > 1. By the  definition of limitation, for $0<\epsilon<(q-p)/2,\ \exists N\in \mathbb N,\ \forall n>N,$
$$n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)>q-\epsilon>p+\epsilon> n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right).$$

Hence
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}< \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n},$$
that is 
$$\forall n>N,\ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_N}< \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_N}.$$

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n $ converges when p > 1, we get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.